# google compute engine vm with apache using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, google-cloud-platform

I have Drupal installed on a google compute engine instance following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setup-drupal the site and MySql seems to have installed. My problem I have tracked down to is the htaccess file is being ignored. If Apache is installed shouldn't that understand the htaccess? It seems you need the rules in the htaccess for Drupal to run properly, yet the tutorial explains nothing about how you'd fix this issue. I've found stuff about the app.yml which is the same sort of thing but I'm unsure how I create/find this file let alone how I convert the rewrite rules in the htaccess to the app.yml! Any ideas?

I just want Drupal to work on Google Compute Engine and the bit stopping me at present is the htaccess file not working, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Apache virtual host configuration allow the htaccess rules. It should contain the line: AllowOverride All. See this link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Yes! I assumed that would be enabled by default, odd they don't mention it in the tutorial either but hey, thanks a lot!